# Using a for loop to write each row of a list of dataframes (only writes last row) in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I have a list of dataframes, I am trying to use a for loop to write each row of each data frame in the list, but it currently only writes the last line of each data frame.

here is a simplified version of the code I'm using:

```
for (i in 1:39){
  for (j in 1:39){
    country.list[[j]]<-data.frame(data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = 39, 
                                                ncol = 10)))
    x<-rnorm(1, mean=5, sd=1)
    y<-rnorm(1, mean=1, sd=1)
    if (is.na(y) | (is.na(y))){
      country.list[[j]][i,]<-NA
    }
    else{
      country.list[[j]][i,]<-rnorm(10, mean=x, sd=y) 
    }
  }
}
```

I'm very new to R, and lists, so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your first line of code overwrites the data.frame everytime you iterate through the `j in 1:39` sequence. Presumably that line should go inside the first loop but outside the second one.

Comment: Could you explain exactly what it is you're trying to do? Are you trying to make a single dataframe out of all the dataframes? If so, you can just use `rbind` (with `rbind` itself, you have to spell out each name, but `do.call(rbind, list_name)` will put them all together in one dataframe, and then you can just print the single dataframe).

Comment: What ever you are trying to do, this is *not* how you do things in R. You should clearly explain what you are trying to achieve and show your esired output.

Comment: Thank-you so incredibly much @Thomas! That completely fixed it

Comment: @DavidArenburg I am working on a model, in which a group of people rank each other. Each dataframe is a person's votes, with the rows as who they are voting for and each column being a simulation. The loop would simulate how one person voted for another person, pasting the values in the rows so then I could rank each column. Sorry for poorly explaining the question. I'm super new to all of this, but I'll try to do better next time. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to create a list of data frames, you could do something like:

```
country.list <- vector(mode="list", length=39)

create.df <- function(.) {
    x <- rnorm(1, mean=5, sd=1)
    y <- rnorm(1, mean=1, sd=1)
    data.frame(
        matrix(replicate(39, {rnorm(10, mean=x, sd=y)}), byrow=T, nrow=39, ncol=10))
}

country.list <- Map(create.df, country.list)
```

However, some values of y produced by this loop will be negative and `rnorm` gives a warning if you try to use a negative SD value, so you probably want to check for that.